# Multiple External IP Addresses, Two Routers & Amazon VPC

Tags: cisco, router, juniper, amazon-vpc

I'm out of my depth here as I'm a database developer trying to do network stuff and really need some help.

We have a leased line with multiple external IP addresses (subnet mask 255.255.255.248).

The gateway is 31.x.x.9 and we currently have a Draytek Vigor 2830n with an external ip address of 31.x.x.10 which is working perfectly for getting us all on the internet.

So our current setup is

Clients <-> Draytek <-> CISCO 1841 (Supplied by ISP) <-> Ether Access Box <-> Outside World

Image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKzVx.jpg

We now have the case where we need to use Amazon VPC and have purchased a Juniper SSG 5 to do this with the intention of using the public IP address 31.x.x.11

I'm stuck at the very first hurdle which is how to connect two routers to the CISCO device and even if having two routers is necessary.

I have a VigorAP 700 which looks like I could use that to add wireless access to the Juniper device and I think I could just use the Juniper device for the whole thing.

EDIT: I do also have a 8 port Netgear FS108 switch, am I wrong in thinking I could use this to connect the Juniper and Draytek Routers to the CISCO router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a small 5 port switch and plug the 'internal' interface of the Cisco (the one currently going to your Draytek) into it, as well as the external interfaces of the Draytek and Juniper. At this point, you will have the same functionality you currently do (simple internet access). Simply configure the Juniper with its public IP and you are done.

Comment: Thank you, that was the correct answer.

I now have two routers working and when I'm physically connected to the Juniper device I can connect to the internet.